# Need assistance in setting up stable diffusion with Anaconda Navigator

Tags: anaconda, stable-diffusion

I am a beginner in setting up stable diffusion locally on my pc and I would like to use Anaconda Navigator to generate AI art. I am quite a geek in overall PC and have mediocre experience in C# programming. But I never ever discovered the world of Python. So I am quite confused in multiple missing libraries, files missing while trying to generate art and I decided to start installation of the Anaconda Navigator and stable diffusion afresh. I used this website guide to set it all up but the command prompt kept on giving me multiple errors, sometimes missing folders, sometimes missing files, sometimes some strange python library.
https://stealthoptional.com/tech/stable-diffusion-nsfw-how-to-make-nsfw-images/

Seems like either this guide is misguiding or something is broken with the provided files which I have downloaded from this same website. Can you please assist me setting up from the very start the entire stable diffusion with Anaconda Navigator??

I tried installing those missing libraries as I was shown in the errors, read multiple sites by searching on google and installed couple of them but the issue kept spiraling out of my mind and decided to uninstall everything completely and start afresh

Comment: You are giving very vague descriptions of what you have done so far and what your errors are that you are seeing. `Can you please assist me setting up from the very start the entire stable diffusion with Anaconda Navigator??` -> This is not the scope of this website and there are tutorials online for setting it up. If you describe what you have done so far and give your specific error messages, we can help you solve your current issue though